# OnChange function not defined when I reference my script as a module?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have a piece of code that implements Cropper.js for interactive cropping of an image. Unfortunately, chrome gives the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: onFileSelected is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onchange ((index):35),"

despite the fact that these functions are clearly defined, when I reference my scripts.js file as

```
<script type="module" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Am I missing something here? Can a script that as loaded as a module not be used for these onchange events? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Top-level variables in modules aren't global. Either explicitly assign them to `window`, or (preferably) pass them around instead, to avoid global pollution

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules